# How to store binary value of a long at a pointer?

Tags: c, void-pointers, systems-programming

I have a void pointer that I would like to store the binary value of a long at. For example:

```
void * p;
long number;

p = malloc(16);
p = memset(p, 0, 16);
number = 15;

/* PRINTS FIRST 16 BYTES */
for(i = 0; i < memSize; i++)
     printf("%02x", ((unsigned char *) p) [i]);
printf("\n");
```

Above code will print

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

I would like to set the first 8 bytes to the value of "number", for example:

```
000000000000000F0000000000000000
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? I suppose bit shifting would work, but that could become quite tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use memcpy?

```
 memcpy (p, &number, sizeof(number));
```

Do you care about the order of bytes (most significant vs least significant first)? Perhaps you should read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: A specific order of bytes is not really necessary since I will be the only the referencing this data. I tried using memcpy, but it did not work as expected. For my test, number = 16; but upon printing the bytes, it returned with 10000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: The first byte is 0x10, which is 16 base 10.  You are running on a machine that has the lest significant byte first (little endian).

Comment: Ahh okay. I was expecting the data to contain leading zeros... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it possible to include leading zeros using memcpy? It just crossed my mind that I will not know the order of magnitude in this format.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
*((uint32_t*)p) = number;
```